# Copying MySQL databases on xampp to Linux from Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, linux, xampp

I decided to move from Windows 10 to Zorin Os. So far, so good. Everything is nice and feels familiar except for xampp. I believed all I had to do was to make a backup of my xampp on win10 specifically htdocs and mysql folders(though I copied everything just in case) and then copy that into the respective folders on Linux. Now I'm getting a **can't select database error** when I load a website and I when I open phpmyadmin, the database tables don't appear on the side like they did previously on windows 10. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: Export from Windows phpmyadmin, import to Linux phpmyadmin or use cli to do both `mysqldump` and `mysql dbname < dbname.sql`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have already uninstalled windows, is there no other option but to put it back?

Comment: I don't know where WAMP stores it, but the database is not stored with the htdocs.  Maybe the files from mysql directory can be copied to Linux, not sure.